# Nginx (Reverse Proxy) gzip compression working for GET but not for POST requests

Tags: nginx, post, proxy, get, reverse

I'm using Nginx as a reverse proxy for my server and have enabled gzip compression. Here's the relevant configuration in my nginx.conf:

```
http {

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    # Gzip Settings
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    server {
        listen localhost:8090;

        location / {
            client_max_body_size 100M;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3090;
            proxy_read_timeout 600s;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

    }
}
```

As far as I understand, NGINX can compress content when acting as a reverse proxy, even if the proxied server doesn't perform compression on its own?

With this configuration, when I make GET requests, the data arrives compressed, but for POST requests, the data doesn't appear to be gzip compressed.
Can anyone help me understand why this might be happening and how to ensure gzip compression for POST requests?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior depends on status code. Compression enabled for the following statuses: `200`, `403` and `404`.

For details, see ticket: https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/394